# Angular 4 http post request to google captcha api fails

Tags: angular, http, post

I'm trying to verify my captcha response by using angular 4's http library and google's siteverify api.
For some reason in the console it's printing:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

And

> ERROR Object { _body: error, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Object, type: 3, url: null }

When i check my network tab it seems successfull:

[image: Network]

[image: Network]

Here's my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, URLSearchParams, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class CaptchaService {
  captchaUrl = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
  secretKey = 'SECRETKEY';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  verifyCaptcha = function(captchaResponse) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let body = new URLSearchParams;
    body.set('secret', this.secretKey);
    body.set('response', captchaResponse);
    return this.http.post(this.captchaUrl, body, { headers: headers })
    .map((response) => response.json())
    .subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
  }
}
```

I'm sorry if this is a nooby question, but i'm new to angular.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok turns out it was just google missing the cors headers.... I was able to fix this problem by having my own api send the request to google and then return it to me.